# What will be the mongodb query for getting array of objects values in separate rows?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my mongo record. here roles is an array of objects. I want short code of roles in multiple rows.

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"),
       "roles" : [
           {
            "name" : "Computer Programme Manager",
            "shortCode" : "COMP"
           },
           {
            "name" : "Technical Manager",
            "shortCode" : "TEMR"
           },
           {
            "name" : "Technical-Civil",
            "shortCode" : "TEMR"
           }
       ],
       "deptDbValue" : "i_a",
       "deptDisplayValue" : "IA",
       "deptShortCode" : "gic"
  }
```

I want all the roles in row wise. I tried this query:

```
db.departments.distinct("roles.shortCode");
```

which is giving each role in separates rows which is correct, but how can I get other properties like `deptShortCode`, `deptDbValue` etc.

For example, I wanted like this:

```
id                 |    role_name         |      role_shortcode
ObjectId("111..")  |    Computer Prog     |      COMP
ObjectId("111..")  |    Technical Manager |      TEMR            
ObjectId("111..")  |    Technical-Civil   |      TEMR
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output format of a MongDB query is typically JSON and what you are suggesting as output format is not possible.

But the data you intended to have in the output could be present in the response of your query. For example:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"), "name" : "Computer Programme Manager", "shortCode" : "COMP" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"), "name" : "Technical Manager", "shortCode" : "TEMR" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"), "name" : "Technical-Civil", "shortCode" : "TEMR" }
```

This is quite close to the output you want to have and correct JSON.

You can achieve this output with $unwind (causes the rows to multiply) and then $project (used to transform each single row) in an aggregate query like this one:

```
db.dummy.aggregate(
[
    {                 
        $unwind: {
            "path": "$roles"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "name": "$roles.name",
            "shortCode": "$roles.shortCode",
        }
    }
] 
)
```

Here is some information on the unwind command:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

and on the project command:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: Thanks @gil.fernandes. Actually I wanted this query only. Again thanks a lot. And sure I will go through the links you have shared. 